# java package vs System in JAVA

Tags: java

I am just learning JAVA (again in a very long time) and I have a simple question.  What is the difference between `java.something` and `System.something`?

The beginner book I got is not thorough enough to explain this (at least not yet).

Comment: I don't get it. Please give an example

Comment: `java.lang` includes the `System` class which holds a collection of static methods and variables.

Comment: Downvoters: Don't downvote questions because you think it's too simple. It's a perfectly valid beginner's question.

Comment: @Jesper I agree. I've upvoted mainly to balance the cosmic karma.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `java.something`, this is a package: a package contains various classes that are available for use in your program. If you want to use a particular class--say, `java.util.Random`--you can either refer to it in full as `java.util.Random`, or have an `import` line at the top of your class that tells Java where to find the `Random` class, and then refer to it just as `Random`.

`System` is a class, and it's contained in the `java.lang` package. (And `java.lang` classes are always imported into your project, so you don't need the `import` line in this case.) When you refer to `System.something()`, you're referring to the `System` class, and invoking the `something()` method of that class.

Most of the time, if you want to invoke method `something()` on class `Someclass`, then you create an instance of `Someclass` and then call `something()` on it:

```
Someclass x = new Someclass();
x.something();
```

but for a `static` method, you invoke it without needing to create an instance. The methods of `System` are static, so you just invoke them as

```
System.something();
```

without creating an instance of type `System`.

Comment: I am not new to programming... I know C# and other languages pretty well.  My main question was regarding the System vs java routes of accessing classes.  I think duffymo hit the nail on the head.  Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, classes and interfaces are organized in [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) (<- click to go to the tutorial).

Class `System` is one of the classes in the package `java.lang`.

If you see for example `System.out`, it means you are doing something with the member variable `out` which is part of class `System`.

When you see for example `java.util.Date`, then it means you are using the class `Date` which is in the package `java.util`. You can either use the fully qualified name of the class, which is `java.util.Date`, or you can `import` the class and then just use the class name `Date`:

```
// At the beginning of your source file
import java.util.Date;

// Now you can just use the short name Date instead
// of the long name java.util.Date
Date now = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but `System.something` is really shorthand for `java.lang.System.something`.  You're referring to the System class in the JDK.

If you see `java.something`, it's going to be a package name built into the JDK (e.g. `java.sql`, `java.util`, etc.)  That's reserved by Sun/Oracle for JDK packages.

Answer (score 0):

System class belongs to java.lang package and all classes in the java.lang package are imported by default so you do not need to import java.lang.*;

On the other hand to use class from java.something package you must write package name with class name

```
Object obj = new java.something.YourClass();
```

or you must use import statement

```
import java.something.YourClass;
...
Object obj = new YourClass();
```